# Strongname Signing IKVM PDFBox for Word Addin

Tags: pdfbox, strongname, ikvm, word-addins

for a Word Addin I am using PDFBox to manipulate PDFs. Or rather I would like to use it. I used it before with a self-created Desktop App. PDFBox is a Java Library that can be made usable as DLLs with IKVM (like here: **http://www.squarepdf.net/pdfbox-in-net** ). The problem that I experience is that all libraries for Wordaddins must be strongnamed. I tried to strongname sign but then I get an exception that a part of apache common logging (in directory MANIFEST.MF) cannot be found.
I know this is pretty vague so far and I will post more details later on, but maybe someone already went through this and has an idea on how to do this right or can point me to some place where there is already a strongnamed version of PDFBox.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I will give some more information to this question, because my colleague is in holiday. I have strong named all pdfbox-dlls and on the try to open a pdf, i will get the first  FileNotFoundException.  The File $(PrjectDir)\bin\x86\Debug\commons-logging.properties could not be found.

All following Exceptions has the same problem. As a sample the next exception is a DirectoryNotFoundException. It could not find \bin\x86\Debug\META-INF\services\org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory . There are more than 10 FileNotFoundExceptions only at the opening of my PDF:

```
doc = PDDocument.load(new File(inputFile));
```

All of Them can't find something of the Logger.

In the next Step, i try to make a content Stream from the first page of that pdf:

```
contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, (PDPage)doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0), true, false);
```

The first Exception, i will become there is another FileNotFoundException for C:\Users(user).accessibility.properties or $(ProjectDir)\bin\x86\Debug\META-INF\services\java.text.spi.NumberFormatProvider

Until this point, i have 20 Exceptions or so. The most of them can't find something of the logger. But i can write the opened pdf to the harddisk. If i try to insert some text into contentstream, i get a harder Exception at the point i have to set the font:

```
PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
contentStream.setFont(font, 10);
```

At this point i get following Exception:

An exception (first chance) of type "System.TypeInitializationException" occurred in fontbox-1.8.12.dll.
Additional information: The type initializer for "org.apache.fontbox.cmap.CMap" generated an exception.

I think the references has a problem, if pdfbox is strong named. Has anybody an idea, what is to do? Thank you very much.